# File systems and writing one

Tags: operating-systems, filesystems

I am going through the following series of lectures on OS development .

http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/

In the fourth tutorial , I came across the term " OEM" parameter block that stores the windows MBR and the Boot-record information whose soul purpose is to describe the file system on the disk .

And then  on moving to the following tutorial ,by taking the authors promise to explain about it at a later opportune point , I came across the term "FAT" file system . And I could see that there were few terms in the parameter block  like "bpbNumberofFATS" and "bpbsectorsperFAT" . 
"FAT" stands for "File Allocation Table" and it is a again a "filesystem" .

This got me confused as "OEM" parameter block is used to describe the filesystem on a disk . And if "FAT" itself is a file system , then that means and surely there are other file systems ,which could have been on that disk . Why will the "OEM" block predefine the file system in terms of "FAT".

On reading a bit about other file systems , I came across statements like "FAT was written by .." . And it further piqued me to ask , what does it mean to write a filesystem ?

So , basically I am confused about :

1. What exactly is a filesystem ? (Is it a kind of coordinate system to provide information about the storage of the contents of the file ?)
2. How is a file system written ?

   3. There are a lots of other file systems , OEM is used to describe the file system on a disk , so why OEM has parameters concerned about FAT's ? And who sets the filesystem of a disk and how ?

Answer (score 2):

The [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) refers to the format used by (many but not all, and slowly being replaced by [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table)) disk to identity partitions. A partition is simply a contiguous range of blocks on the disk. A partition is often used to store data, in the form of files and directories. But of course a disk knows nothing about files and directories. A [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) is a system that controls how your data is stored on the disk. A file system is really two things:

- it specifies how the data is organized and accessed (directories, files, links, permissions, encryption, ...): this is the logical aspect
- it specifies how this data is encoded on the disk: this is physical aspect

There exists **many** file systems: FAT, exFAT, NTFS, ext, btrfs, HFS, XFS,  ISO 9660 and others. [FAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) is a file system invented by Microsoft. What this means is that they designed the logical and physical aspects of it, and they applied and were granted a few patents on it. They also wrote the Windows driver for FAT, but note that anyone can do that (assuming the file system is properly documented and ignoring royalties issues) and indeed linux and MacOS have their own driver which follows Windows's specification.

Now as I explained a file system specifies how the data is encoded on the disk and FAT is not exception. The first sector of a FAT partition (also known as the boot sector, or super block) is what is described in the link you gave: is starts with 3 bytes for a jump instruction and is followed by the BIOS/OEM Parameter Block (which has a different format on FAT12, FAT16 and FAT32). **This OEM block is specific to FAT** and does not exist on other file systems. Other file systems use a different format. I might add that calling this the OEM/BIOS block was very unfortunate because it really has little to do with BIOS or OEM, but that was the name Microsoft came up with. It should really be called the FAT Parameter Block.

To finish, designing a good file system is hard because they are many trade-offs to make. FAT is simple and relatively robust, but sucks at about everything else if I may say. Sadly it is also the only file system that all OSes support and so is the de facto standard for interoperability.

Comment: So , how  off would it be  to say that it is a kind of coordinate system for files ? On what basis do we compare the technical efficiency  of different file systems ?

Comment: I would say it is a correct description at the high-level for simple file systems. But file systems can provide a number of other functionalities, such as transactions, encryption, reliability against crash/error, snapshots, copy-on-write, and so on, that make this analogy not quite right. Comparing the efficiency of different file systems is not trivial because of various trade-offs. Some want fast FS, some want reliable FS (in case of crash or errors), some want snapshopts.

Comment: Here is an example of benchmark for file systems: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux414-fs-compare&num=2 mostly focused on speed.

Comment: What makes a file system faster as compared to other ? Will it be a kind of reasoning that makes operations like sorting in a heap or B-tree faster as compared to the operation in an array ?

Comment: There are many reasons. Some are structural: if the file systems uses some clever structure on disk like B-trees, then some operations are faster. But there are other factors: some file systems will work better on rotating disks, some better on SSD, some better on raw NAND. The quality of the driver and the operating system is crucial as well. Also the I/O pattern is extremely important. There is no simple answer.

Comment: Please pardon me if there is any lack of coherence in my questions , but a file system is a property of the disk right not of the OS right ? So , when I will be writing an OS , like I would be the starting up with the bootloader program , something or someone b then must have fixed the filesystem of the disk , right ? How might has that been done ?

Comment: Yes a file system is a property of the disk (or the disk is an instance of the file system specification). Each OS needs to have one or more file system **drivers**, that follow the file system specification. But when one starts writing an OS, usually one does not use a file system. It is simpler to just put the bootloader and kernel on a partition at fixed location or with a simple header.

Comment: Also there is a book called "Practical File System Design with the Be File System" which I have never read but is available online and might answer your questions about how to design a file system.

Comment: The following part of the above mentioned tutorial :
http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev6.html

Is FAT assumed to be preexisting in this disk ? And would the bootloader have been different ,had it been a different file system ?

Comment: Is it the file driver  that you were referring to ? So before writing an OS for a system do I need to know the file system existing already in it ?

Comment: In http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev5.html, the file system is built into the bootloader image (that's why the bootloader code embeds the FAT PBP/OEM header). In http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev6.html, the tutorial develops the file system driver: that is the code to read files from the disk. You should really read a book/tutorial on OS architecture those things are unclear to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Amaury for your time . I was planning to read few books on OS first but I thought it would be better to know "what exactly it means to write an operating system "  and this is why I first took this tutorial .

Comment: So two small questions before I start on the plan suggested by you .. what exactly does an "image" mean technically ? And what does it mean by file system being "built into the bootloader image" ? Does it mean that this bootloader is mounting the FAT filesystem  on this disk or  FAT system is assumed to be existing in this disk and the bootloader is using this to read the files ?

Answer (score 2):

### **OEM Parameter block**

The OEM block not only stores data about the *filesystem*, it also contains information about the *physical hard drive geometry*, or about how files are laid out on your hard drive or SSD. This was used by older BIOSes to determine how a hard drive was set up from the manufacturer.
As a good primer for explaining hard drive geometry, I can suggest [this chapter on pcguide.com](http://pcguide.com/ref/hdd/geom/index.htm) [, and this one](http://www.pcguide.com/ref/hdd/bios/bios.htm)

Important geometry parameters I can see are:

- **bpbBytesPerSector**: Which describes the sector size. This is basically the smallest unit of data that *anything* can write to the drive. It's usually 512 bytes, but newer large drives may use 1024 byte or larger sectors.
- **bpbSectorsPerCluster**: Which indicates how large a cluster is in # of sectors. A cluster is the smallest unit of data the *filesystem* can manage
- **bpbSectorsPerTrack**: The number of sectors per physical *track* on a hard drive

This method is, however an obsolete method of determining the size of a hard drive. Since the late 90s, Logical Block Addressing has taken over, which in itself is basically a direct method of counting and mappping every sector or block on a hard drive or SSD. However BIOSes and modern OSes still use it for legacy purposes.

To answer your Question # 3, FAT is the very first filesystem written for IBM-compatible PCs. This is likely a throwback to FAT 12 and 16 and earlier implementations of the OEM parameter block specification. As with many other HDD-related quirks in the IBM/x86 family it's likely that it's been left there for legacy purposes.
Earlier FAT implementations (and fat12, still) could only write a single partition to a disk.
Also, FAT partitions usually contain 2 allocation tables, the main table and a backup table for integrity and error-correction purposes.

### **What is a filesystem?**

Basically a means of getting disorganized data assigned into a system that can be understood by us, as well as the computer. Your assumption of it being a "coordinate system" for files is not inaccurate.

A very basic filesystem has to do the following:

- Map a given file to a set of sectors/clusters
- Provide a way to *distinguish* one file from the next (eg. start and end address)
- Provide a way for the user to locate needed data (eg. by a *filename*)
- Provide a way for *the rest of the hardware and software* to easily understand how data is to be read and written according to hardware and OS rules (abstraction layer, API, or what you prefer to call it nowadays)
- Provide a way to *protect* data and indicate that a given section of the HDD/SSD is occupied and other basic information or limitations (eg. write protect bit, file size, file attributes)
- Provide a way to remap data, so that the medium is used most effeciently

Optionally a file system also provides extra aids for improving reliability (by saving important data in multiple places or providing error correction mechanisms), speed (eg. by using search indexes), security (encryption, permissions) or user experience (Sorting files by using folders or providing easy access by using shortcut files or symbolic links)

It is very important to know, for all intents and purposes, that the way your file manager shows you the files is NOT the way the data is actually laid out on the drive. An effecient filesystem has to be able to *remap* data. For more on that, I suggest you read up on [this very informative chapter](http://www.pcguide.com/ref/hdd/file/clust.htm)